# Android NFC scanner issue

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm developing a `NFC` scanning feature for my `Android` application. It works on all my devices except on a `Samsung S4` running `Android 4.4.2`.

When I scan a `NFC tag`, it throws this error:

```
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED dat=vnd.android.nfc://ext/android.com:pkg cmp=com.mobile.planning/.NfcDebugActivity (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=10200) not exported from uid 10202
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820): Unable to send startActivity intent
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED dat=vnd.android.nfc://ext/android.com:pkg cmp=com.mobile.planning/.NfcDebugActivity (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=10200) not exported from uid 10202
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1669)
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:977)
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:4182)
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:252)
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.send(PendingIntentRecord.java:192)
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820):     at android.content.IIntentSender$Stub.onTransact(IIntentSender.java:64)
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
03-04 17:09:34.570: W/ActivityManager(820):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Apparently, it seems to be a permission error. Which is really strange because it does work on my `LG L65` and on my `Samsung ACE 4`.

In my `Manifest.xml`, I've added the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />
```

The `Activity` has been declared like that:

```
<activity
        android:name=".NfcDebugActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

The `NFC` feature has been enabled on each device and it works with apps you can easily find on the `Play Store`.

Do you have any idea why this error is triggered ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states, your activity is not exported. An activity is exported by default only if it has an `<intent-filter>`, and yours does not.

Now, *why* it would need to be exported, I can't say, as I would either have expected you to have some `<intent-filter>` *or* to be using a `PendingIntent` as part of your NFC setup. The latter allows other processes to start your activity even though it is not exported.

The workaround would be to add `android:exported="true"` to the `<activity>` element in the manifest. That makes this activity publicly accessible, though, and so you would want to take that into account.